# making code that throws exception not terminate loop

Tags: r

I am trying this (apologies this is not reproducible but hopefully someone can help please):

```
for (row in 1:nrow(combinations)) {

    tryCatch({
            ba_search <- BayesianOptimization( 
            aq_function,
            bounds = bayesian_search_bounds
            # some more parameters
             )
         },
     finally = {
     
        if (exists("ba_search")) {
            # do something with the results
        } else {
            # do some default because of exception
        }
     }
     
     })
}
```

The intention is to execute:

```
# do some default because of exception
```

if an exception occurs, rather than terminate the script/loop.

Unfortunately, the script/loop still terminates. Any help to fix this would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error handling is done by an `error` function, not by `finally`, see [Exceptions handling](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html).
The following loop runs as expected:

```
for (row in 1:3) {
  
  tryCatch({
    print(row)
    if (row==2) {ba_search <- "ba_search created"}
    stop("Error triggered")
      # some more parameters
  },
  error = function(c){
    if (exists("ba_search")) {
      # do something with the results
      print(paste("Error after ba_search creation",c))
    } else {
      # do some default because of exception
      print(paste("Error without ba_search:",c))
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks will try later ... bit strange as every other language would hit the final part anyway - e.g. to close open connection etc.